# Objects 3D face corner positions to UVs

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to convert a 3D objects face corner positions to UVs?

I want to deform an objects mesh, save it as UV and then reapply those as UVs.
I want to create a UV map in geometry nodes without the unwrap node.

Here is a blend setup as explanation:

[image]

[ObjectPosToUV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19mpevdGs_vqyTNkoJVGFRVwAWAJAjGIP/view?usp=drive_link)

I tried many setups including Sample Index, but never could get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

[How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3050/60486)

Your link doesn't work, no access.

You don't need to deform your mesh temporarily, or on a copy to sample the UV from. Just deform your positions directly:

[image]

BTW it makes no sense, when evaluating in "Face Corner" domain, to use the "evaluate on domain: face corner".

Comment: actually the vector math: multiply is not even needed there because it's a 2D vector so $z$ component is discarded.